# If Statement not meeting Condition for Specific Condition Value [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

My code has a loop that is finding whether the value of a given column in a pivot table is the min/max of that row. A caveat is certain rows have a characteristic entry repeated, so I have a set of If ElseIf conditions to skip the copying process for these entries. The code is as follows:

```
    For i = 0 To 339
    wfr = wfr + CStr(i + 5)
    Sheets("ET Pivot").Select
    If Sheets("ET Pivot").Range(wfr).Value = 7 Then
        GoTo LoopExit
    ElseIf Sheets("ET Pivot").Range(wfr).Value = 9 Then
        GoTo LoopExit
    ElseIf Sheets("ET Pivot").Range(wfr).Value = 99999.99 Then
        GoTo LoopExit
    ElseIf Sheets("ET Pivot").Range(wfr).Value = 1 Then
        GoTo LoopExit
    End If
    If Sheets("ET Pivot").Range(wfr).Value = Sheets("ET Pivot").Range("AB" + CStr(i + 5)).Value Then
       Sheets("ET Pivot").Select
       Sheets("ET Pivot").Rows(i + 5 & ":" & i + 5).Select
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("ET Outliers").Select
       Sheets("ET Outliers").Range("A" + CStr(ic)).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       ic = ic + 1
   ElseIf Sheets("ET Pivot").Range(wfr).Value = Sheets("ET Pivot").Range("AC" + CStr(i + 5)).Value Then
       Sheets("ET Pivot").Select
       Sheets("ET Pivot").Rows(i + 5 & ":" & i + 5).Select
       Selection.Copy
       Sheets("ET Outliers").Select
       Sheets("ET Outliers").Range("A" + CStr(ic)).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       ic = ic + 1
   End If
LoopExit:
   wfr = wfrc
Next i
```

The first four If statements are the skip conditions. The conditions 9, 99999.99, and 1 work as planned. For some reason, the 7 condition does not trigger the If statement. I have made sure the cell value is actually 7 and not rounded, I have changed the order of the conditions, and I have added a dummy condition first, all to no avail. I'm not sure why this specific case is not working.

Comment: Are you sure nothing in the code is misspelled or contains an "odd" character? Have you tried copy/pasting a line that works, then subsituting the value? (Side note: Any particular reason you're not using Select Case instead of all these ElseIf?)

Comment: What is the idea of the statement `wfr = wfr + CStr(i + 5)`? What datatype and initial value (before you enter the loop) has `wfr`?

Comment: @FunThomas:   wfr is a single letter string that contains a column value, so wfr + CStr(i+5) is a specific cell (eg. F5)

Comment: @Cindy Meister:   I'm not using Select Case because I taught myself VBA and I don't know about many functions, including Select Case

Comment: Have you tried to cast it as an integer, which will force the value to be 7 if it's within rounding range?  `If CInt(Sheets("ET Pivot").Range(wfr).Value) = 7`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so there are a few things to unpack here. Here are the things I changed:

1. Reduced the reliance on `.Select` by explicitly stating what sheets you want to access for each range.
2. Combined your `if` statements - this makes the code easier to read and edit

   a. For the first group of `if`s this meant that we could get rid of your `LoopExit` because it no longer served a purpose

   b. For the second set of `if`s it let us take out a big chunk of repetitive code
3. Changed the way that you access values from concatenating strings to using `.Cells(row,col)`

   a. This change let me get rid of `wfr` and replace it with just `"A"`
4. Adjusted the value of `i` in your loop since you were always saying `i + 5`
5. Changed the `paste` method to `Range().copy destination:=Range()`

Hope this helps!

```
Dim i As Long
Dim ic As Long
Dim current As Double

For i = 5 To 334

    current = Sheets("ET Pivot").Cells(i, "A").Value2

    If current <> 1 And current <> 7 And current <> 9 And current <> 99999.99 Then

        If current = Sheets("ET Pivot").Cells(i, "AB").Value2 Or current = Sheets("ET Pivot").Cells(i, "AC").Value2 Then

            Sheets("ET Pivot").Rows(i & ":" & i).copy _
                Destination:=Sheets("ET Outliers").Cells(ic, "A")

            ic = ic + 1

        End If

    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it thanks to @Jaberwocky .

Rather than converting it to an integer as he recommended, I rounded it to 3 decimal places and checked whether it was equal to 7. The reason for this difference is converting to an integer will inadvertently filter out max/min values from 6.51 to 7.5, which may be elsewhere in the data set.

It seems that the "7" numbers I am trying to filter out aren't actually the integer 7, even though the deviation isn't shown when 30 decimal places are displayed.

Thanks to everybody for the input.